# Reading and parsing integers from a text file

Tags: c#, parsing, file-io

I'm trying to get a line of integers from a text file and parse them into separate variables. The text file is set up like this:

ID:HP:MP:STR:WIS:SPD:GOLD:XP

0:100:50:10:5:12:5:10

I want to split them with the : symbol in between each. One of the problems I'm having with this is being able to read the file line by line as strings, parsing them, and then storing the parsed strings as ints. Here is the code I'm attempting to use so far:

```
class monster
{
    string line;
    string[] mstats;
    string[] mname;
    char[] delimeterChars = {':'};
    int id;
    int i = -1;
    int j = 0;
    int hp;
    int mp;
    int str;
    int wis;
    int spd;
    int gold;
    int xp;

    public monster(int id)
    {
        StreamReader stats = new StreamReader("monsterStats.txt");
        while(i != id)
        {
            i++;
            line = stats.ReadLine();
            mstats = line.Split(delimeterChars);
            j = 0;
            foreach(string s in mstats)
            {
                if (j == 0) id = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 1) hp = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 2) mp = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 3) str = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 4) wis = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 5) spd = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 6) gold = int.Parse(s);
                else if (j == 7) xp = int.Parse(s);
                j++;
            }
        }
        curHp = hp;
        curMp = mp;
        curSpd = spd;
        curStr = str;
        curWis = wis;
    }
}
```

I get the following error when this code runs:

Input string was not in a correct format.
It references this part of the code:

```
if (j == 0) id = int.Parse(s);
```

Comment: Wow, I just realised that the "key" I had at the top of the text file with the ID:HP:MP... was messing everything up lol. Completly forgot that it was up there. Thanks for all the advice on cleaning up the code everyone! First time user here, I'll be sure to come back when I have more questions!

Comment: Oh man, I considered asking if that header line was in the file but thought, "Naaah... can't be that!" :)

Answer (score 3):

Why the `foreach`? How about:

```
id = int.Parse(mstats[0]);
hp = int.Parse(mstats[1]);
```

and so on. With a check beforehand that `mstats` is long enough.

A bit of Linq would let you get an array of integers in one shot:

```
int[] fields = line.Split(delimeterChars).Select(s => int.Parse(s)).ToArray();

id = field[0];
hp = field[2];
```

As for getting the code working, try printing out the line of text, and each piece of text just before you pass it to Parse. If it's not an integer, that's your problem.

Comment: +1 for simplicity.  Be aware that this will throw an exception, as it should, if the column contains a non-integer value.

Comment: +1 for `String.Split` .  Far superior to using a regular expression, for this input.  Also for suggesting printing out the text to see what is wrong.  Obvious but important.

Answer (score 3):

Well, the first thing is to find out what the bad input was.

If you're *expecting* bad input data, use [`int.TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.tryparse.aspx) instead of just [`int.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.parse.aspx). If you're *not* expecting bad input data, the fact that it's throwing an exception is probably appropriate - but you should examine your data to find out what's wrong.

I'd also recommend putting the parsing call *once* rather than in every case. It's not like you're doing a different kind of parsing for each field.

Answer (score 2):

A very good way for parsing text input are always regular expressions.

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<id>\d+):(?<hp>\d+):(?<mp>\d+):(?<str>\d+):(?<wis>\d+):(?<spd>\d+):(?<gold>\d+):(?<xp>\d+)");

// loop over lines
Monster m = new Monster();
Match mc = r.Match(input);

m.hp = GetValue(mc.Groups["hp"], m.hp);
m.mp = GetValue(mc.Groups["mp"], m.mp);
m.str = GetValue(mc.Groups["str"], m.str);
...


// method to handle extracted value
private static int GetValue(Group g, int fallback)
{
    if (g == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("g");
    return g.Success ? Convert.ToInt32(g.Value) : fallback;
}
```

The method GetValue checks the extracted value. If the match failed (perhaps "" or "AB" instead of a number - g.Success is false) you can handle it the way you want. In my way i simply use an fallback value.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs600312.aspx

Comment: don't say "always". there are exceptions. html for example.